# Fetch multiple URLs at the same time?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch-api

I'm looking for a way to fetch multiple URLs at the same time. As far as I know the API can only retrieve the data I want with a single product lookup so I need to fetch multiple products at once with the url structure "/products/productID/". Note, this is in VUEJS. This is what my code looks like so far:

In my productServices.js:

```
const productsService = {
 getCategory(productID){
    const url = `${config.apiRoot}/products/${productID}`

    return fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${authService.getToken()}`
    },
    })
 }
}
```

In my view:

```
data() {
  return {
    featuredProduct: [13,14,15],
    productName: [],
    productImg: []
  }
}
```

```
async mounted(){
    const response = await productsService.getCategory(this.featuredProduct)
    const resJSON = JSON.parse(response._bodyInit)
    this.loading = false
    this.productName = resJSON.name
    this.productImg  = resJSON.custom_attributes[0].value
}
```

So I need to hit all three featuredProduct IDs and store the data. I'm not really sure how to loop through multiple URLS. All of my other API calls have had all the data readily available using search params but for the specific data I need here (  product image ), it can only be seen by calling a single product.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In Angular, there is a `forkJoin` method to get their results until the last one has come by sending multiple request at the same time. You can research `forkJoin` in VueJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have an array of products, I'd start by changing your state names:

```js
data() {
  return {
    productIds: [13, 14, 15],
    productNames: [],
    productImages: [],
  };
},
```

Then you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to fetch the products in parallel:

```js
async mounted() {
  const responses = await Promise.all(
    this.productIds.map(id => productsService.getCategory(id))
  );
  responses.forEach((response, index) => {
    const resJSON = JSON.parse(response._bodyInit);
    this.productNames[index] = resJSON.name;
    this.productImages[index] = resJSON.custom_attributes[0].value;
  });

  this.loading = false;
}
```

You could also consider refactoring `getCategory` do the parsing for you and return an object containing a `name` and an `image` - that way, `mounted` wouldn't have to know about the internal response structure.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm now getting the following error:

[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Which indicates the response is returning undefined.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. Please see the updated code. If that doesn't work, please place a console log inside of your `forEach` loop to see what's returned.

Comment: Thank you, looks like that did the trick. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 26):

Like [Ricardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8106018/ricardo-gonzalez) suggested I'd use `Promise.all`. It takes in an array of promises and resolves the promise **it** returns, once all the passed ones have finished (it resolves the promises in the form of an array where the results have the same order as the requests).

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(resp => resp.json()),
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2').then(resp => resp.json()),
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3').then(resp => resp.json()),
]).then(console.log)
```

Using `map` + `Promise.all` **(tested)**

```js
Promise.all([1, 2, 3].map(id => 
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`).then(resp => resp.json())
)).then(console.log);
```

if you have multiple products in an array which need to be fetched, you could just use:

**Code not tested**

```js
Promise.all(productIds.map(productId => 
  fetch(`https://url/products/${productId}`)
)).then(() => {/* DO STUFF */});
```

Little suggestion on storing your data:

If you store everything in one array, it makes to whole job way easier. So you could do

```
fetchFunction().then(results => this.products = results);

/*
  this.products would then have a structure something like this:
  Array of Obejcts: {
    name: "I'm a name",
    displayName: "Please display me",
    price: 10.4
    // And so on
  }
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the answer below did the trick but this is also good information. I agree, storing the data in one array makes the most sense. That was my next step, just wanted to make sure the to get the fetch working properly. Thanks!

Comment: @user3330820 alright, glad you found what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Promise.all` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Syntax)

Maybe you can create the calls that you need by iterating into your `data` and then request them in bulk.